# While loop ignores conditionals (if, else) and just prints first suggested print option

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, repeat, fizzbuzz

I am trying to create a program that prints out a list of numbers starting at 0 and leading up to a number the user inputs (represented by the variable "number"). I am required to use "while" loops to solve this problem (I already have a functional "for" loop version of the assignment). The program should mark anything in that list divisible by 3 with the word "Fizz," divisible by 5 with the word "Buzz," and anything divisible by both with "FizzBuzz" while also including unlabeled numbers outside of those specifications.

Every time I run this program, it ignores the conditions and just prints the word "FizzBuzz" however many times is represented by the number inputted. (I typically use 15 because it has at least one example of each condition, so that means I get 15 "FizzBuzz"s in a row).

To find out why it was doing that, I used print(i) instead of the rest of the program under the first conditional and it gave me 15 counts of the number 0, so there is reason to believe the program is completely ignoring the range I gave it and just outputting copies of i based on the user number input.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
number = int(input("Enter a Number"))
i = 0
while(i < number + 1):
    if number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0:
        print("Fizzbuzz")
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz")
    elif number % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz")
    else:
        print(number)
    i += 1
print ("Done!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to check the divisibility of `i`, which increments every loop, not of `number` which doesn't change.

You also meant to `print(i)` in the else clause.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! This is the second time I've ever opened Python and I'm not sure how to take your answer into my program, would you mind explaining further?

Comment: @Ghost If you entered `3` it would just print `Fizz`'s. If you entered `5`, it would just print `Buzz`'s. If you entered some number not divisible by 3 or 5 it would just print that number. Does that help?

Comment: I suspected that was the case since when I used print(i) instead of the conditions it just gave me a repeating 0 15 times (the number I used for "number"). How do I get the program to check divisibility of "i" instead of "number?"

Comment: @Ghost Use the `%` operator on `i` instead of `number`, of course.

Comment: Of course! Thanks for your help. It's running smoothly now.